# Page break not breaking

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I want to have page break but it is not working. I tried to post the whole code but it exceed number of characters. I wanted to know what may cause page break not to work.

```css
@media print {
    div.pagebreak {
        display: block !important; 
        page-break-after: always; 
    }
    .dontprint{ 
        display : none
    }
    body{
        display: block;
    }

}
```

```html
<tr ><td><div class="pagebreak"></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: [Note](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp): You cannot use this property on an empty `<div>` or on absolutely positioned elements. And a `&nbsp;` inside the div

Comment: i actually tried it on the table but it didnt work and also made the table look bad so i create a tr with div on it.i tried adding `<span style="display:none">asdasda</span>` still didnt work inside the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
font-size: 10px;
```

I have this in my parent div as style when i remove it it works. Although i dont know why. I hope someone has the answer why this style is not letting the page break to work

Comment: It seems that page-break-after only works on display:block elements

Comment: @JennieJi i think so too

Comment: It's help, I also affected by parent element.

Answer (score 3):

Since I found page-break series only works for `display: block;` items, so I figured out a solution that works for almost any situations.

It is simple. Just add a `div` with following class to wherever you wanna break.

```
.page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
  height: 0;
  display: block;  // optional. must be sure it is block item in document flow
  clear: both;   // optional. use only if you are using float
}
```

Notice that this element cannot be a child of flex element.

So, if you want to make a layout having many blocks, each takes 50% width of page, and page break after every 2 of them, you can do like this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 300px">left</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 400px">right</div>
<div class="page-break">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 300px">left</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 400px">right</div>
```

Comment: display: block; did the job.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
@media print  
{
    div{
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried didnt work i think div cant be empty just like what comment says

Comment: page-break-after property is in progress of being replaced by the more generic break-after property. This new property also handles column and region breaks while being syntactically compatible with page-break-after. Thus before using page-break-after, check if you can use break-after instead