# Element doesn't break properly firefox

Tags: css, firefox, page-break-inside

I have this css code:

```
.parent {
  column-count: 2;
}
p, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  page-break-inside:avoid;
  break-inside:avoid;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="parent">
 <p>lorem ipsum and so on</p>
</div>
```

Chrome v80 (All nice and well):

[image]

Firefox v74:

[image]

[These tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388148/page-break-not-breaking) don't work.
In the [firefox doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)'s it says it should work. But it just doesn't. What am I doing wrong? [Striped codepen](https://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/GRJXmdy)

Answer (score 0):

add `margin:0;` at least to p

```
p{margin:0}
```

Comment: that does nothing

Comment: you're right, it looks like there is a bug on firefox, can't you use flex?